# How to add a plugin to Phonegap Desktop version without CLI?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I've installed the Phonegap Windows Desktop version without CLI.

Now I wish to manually install plugins by copying and pasting the lines into the code. (I need a plugin to read device details such as IMEI number, etc.)

What is the step by step procedure to installing a plugin manually? I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me.

Comment: is there any specific reason you can't use cli?

Comment: I've installed Phonegap desktop because I thought it would be easier. Can I use CLI at the same time?